# Keras model to predict probability distribution

Tags: python, keras

We are trying to build a keras model to predict a vector with probablity rates from a vector of features. The output vector should be of probabilty rates which are between 0 and one and to sum to 1, but some how the output vector consists mostly of zeros and ones, moreover during the time which the model should be training and learn loss and val_loss rates remains the same.

Does anyone knows what is the problem with our model?

example of input vector:

> (0,4,1444997,0,622,154536,0,2,11,0,5,11,10,32,4.26E-04,0,5,498,11,1,11,0,172,0,4,1,8,150)

example of expected output vector:

> (0.25,0,0,0.083333333,0.583333333,0.083333333)

example of real output vector:

> (1.000000000000000000e+00,5.556597260531319618e-28,1.000000000000000000e+00,0.000000000000000000e+00,0.000000000000000000e+00,0.000000000000000000e+00)

the code:

```
# Create first network with Keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras import optimizers

import numpy
X = numpy.loadtxt("compiledFeatures.csv", delimiter=",")
Y = numpy.loadtxt("naive_compiledDate.csv", delimiter=",")

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=28, init='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(15, init='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, init='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, init='normal', activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile model
model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = 'mae')
# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=2000,  verbose=2, validation_split = 0.15)
# calculate predictions
predictions = model.predict(X)
```

Comment: swap 'sigmoid' in the last layer to 'softmax'

Comment: I think your loss function should be cross entropy instead of 'mae' as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last activation function to guarantee that the sum is 1 is "softmax".

Now, a frozen loss may be caused by "relu" in this case where you have so few neurons in each layer. (Also a improper weight initialization)

I suggest instead of relu you use "softplus", "tanh" or even "sigmoid".

EDIT:

As @nuric suggested, it's really a good idea to use "categorical_crossentropy" as loss when you're using "softmax".

Comment: If `softmax` is used as the activation I would recommend switching to `categoritcal_crossentropy` loss.